# What is the expected orientation for Gibson guitar headstock stampings?

Tags: guitar

Recently I saw a (reverse) headstock photo of a Gibson guitar where the serial number was stamped in the traditional "horizontal" style, but the "Made in USA" was stamped "vertically". I've never seen that before, and it made me suspicious.

Can anyone verify that they've seen similar stampings on a legitimate Gibson guitar? That is, serial number and "Made in USA" stampings oriented at 90-degrees to one another. Here is another example that I just found: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Vintage-Gibson-ES-175-Guitar-/222766009457

Fyi, while researching this question, I discovered some helpful information concerning the headstock logos (see http://forum.gibson.com/index.php?/topic/74747-gbsons-headstock-logos/ for details). I thought that the "closed b" and "closed o" logo on my 1985 Howard Roberts went back much further into history, but this resource declares that '"pantograph" style, closed "b" and "o": 1969-1984'.

For related information, see [What indicators enable consumers to identify counterfeit guitars?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/20552/what-indicators-enable-consumers-to-identify-counterfeit-guitars)

Comment: It seems like you answered your own question in the fyi, or are you still looking for more resources?  Are you concerned about counterfeit Gibson?

Comment: Yes, precisely. I am attempting to confirm that this stamping orientation is a solid indicator for suspicion.. I am skeptical of this particular listing, and others for various reasons. In this listing, the back of the body shows two potential clues: 1) discoloration atypical of the wood grade generally selected for Natural (blonde) models, and 2) what appears to be a seam atypical of the rotary cut plies.

Comment: I see.  I hope you get some answers.  We are all concerned about fakes, with Chinese Gibsons and Gibson filing for bankruptcy last year.  But I'm not up to date on this issue, haven't bought a guitar since 1994 and don't plan to.

Comment: Taking a broader look at eBay listings for "gibson es (natural, blonde)", it strikes me as unexpected that so many are selling from one particular country.