# I want to know about this guitar. it's real yamaha product or fake?

Tags: acoustic-guitar

[image][image]
I want to know about this guitar. it's real yamaha product or fake? plz

Comment: I don't feel like a Yamaha made in Taiwan is the kind of thing someone would be highly motivated to fake. That's like a fake nickel. It would cost more to fake a nickel than a nickel is worth.

Comment: And yet, it most likely is fake. The label is wrong, the logo is wrong. Very similar question: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11229/is-my-yamaha-guitar-counterfeit?rq=1

Comment: A close-up of the headstock might help too; the fakes always seem to get the M wrong & often the 'leaf' logo is nowhere near as sharp as an original. As @Johannes already said, the label looks wrong too, the outline & overall sticker shape should be the same.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - if you can sell a £25 guitar for £300 it's probably worth someone's time to do it. If bought from eBay etc, then who would ever know? If bought through a 'real' retailer, I'd be very interested in asking them about their current standing with that territory's Yamaha  Distributor.

Comment: People pay that much for a Taiwanese Yamaha? You could get a Japanese Fender for that much!

Comment: Yamaha make good instruments.

Comment: The sticker also has dotted lines for cutting. This is something I do (only way fainter) when setting up paper labels etc. for quicker hand-cutting. Legit Yamaha labels would be die-cut.

Comment: This is not a good topic here - it is not theory and practice, and while this particular instance may be quite obvious, some fakes are so good it is difficult for experts to tell the difference even when they have them in their hands. Not a good fit for an online Q&A site, and not a good fit with our site scope.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's fake, the label is worrying, clumsily printed & doesn't match the shape of the printed oval to the shape of the actual sticker.

*A picture of the headstock from the OP would help to check the logo & font used more closely, fakes tend to get the M wrong.*
Note the centre of the M shouldn't reach the baseline.

Just to provide some pictorial comparison, this is the label, serial number (ringed) & headstock from a real [if not magnificent] Yamaha acoustic.

[image]

[image]

Another thing to worry about is that no Yamaha pure acoustic has a cutaway - only the 'electric' acoustics have that.

Compare -
[Yamaha Acoustics](http://uk.yamaha.com/en/products/musical-instruments/guitars-basses/ac-guitars/#list=all&mode=paging)
[Yamaha Electric Acoustics](http://uk.yamaha.com/en/products/musical-instruments/guitars-basses/el-ac-guitars/#list=all&mode=paging)

Answer (score 0):

Yamaha seems to have only sold FG 720 S models. I can't find any FG 720 C models, even in their list of discontinued models. On the basis of this, I would argue it's a fake.